# Is the theory that dwarf women look like dwarf men limited to the works of Tolkien?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, dwarves

We saw Gimli discussing dwarf women with Eowyn in the *The Two Towers*:

> Gimli: It's true you don't see many dwarf women. And in fact, they are
>   so alike in voice and appearance, that they are often mistaken for
>   dwarf men.
>
> Aragorn: [whispering] It's the beards.
>
> Gimli: And this in turn has given rise to the belief that there are no dwarf women, and
>   that dwarves just spring out of holes in the ground!
>
> [Eowyn laughs]
>
> Gimli: Which is, of course, ridiculous.

Is the theory that dwarf women look like dwarf men limited to the works of Tolkien?

Comment: That scene is in *The Two Towers*, at least in the movie. I don't remember if that scene even occurred in the books.

Comment: @GabeWillard it's not, although it is a paraphrase of a passage in the Prologue.

Comment: Tolkien has been imitated so much that pretty much _nothing_ in his works is unique anymore. A more useful way to phrase this question might thus be whether the idea was _original_ to Tolkien, or whether it also appears in earlier sources. In any case, [this TV Tropes page might be relevant](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OurDwarvesAreAllTheSame).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, in Terry Pratchett's Discworld series, female [dwarfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarfs_%28Discworld%29) are bearded and indistinguishable from males. It's an homage to Tolkien, of course.

Comment: Unless they wear high-heeled combat boots, pink bows in their beards, and make-up.

Answer (score 5):

As well, the EverQuest series of games also allows for you to customize your dwarf female characters with beards.