# Did Tolkien originate the idea of dwarven women as being visually indistinguishable from dwarven men?

Tags: history-of, dwarves, tolkiens-legendarium

Inspired by this question: [Is the theory that dwarf women look like dwarf men limited to the works of Tolkien?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27076/is-the-theory-that-dwarf-women-look-like-dwarf-men-limited-to-the-works-of-tolki)

The answer to the above question is no as there are other works which continue the trend of dwarven men and women being indistinguishable from one another. However, the examples provided in the answers to that question are all relatively recent.

As the title states, I'm wondering if there are any works which pre-date Tolkien that also describe or depict them as being nearly identical in appearance. Note that I'm **not** looking for a list of works, I'm simply after a "yes" or "no" answer - though in the case of a "yes" answer I'd also be looking for a single example as proof.

For the sake of this question we'll consider pre-dating Tolkien to be any work produced prior to 1937, which is when (according to Wikipedia) *The Hobbit* was published and he began writing *The Lord of the Rings*.

Comment: You'll have to specify whether such a race would need to be called "dwarves" to qualify and/or whether they have to look and act like Tolkien's dwarves.

Comment: Women indistinguishable from men in an ancient trope going all the way back to the Amazons, if not earlier.  Tolkien certainly wasn't doing anything new here.  For Dwarves specifically you'll need to look at Norse mythology as that's where he largely lifted them from.

Comment: Closed-as-list in 3..2..1..

Comment: @mh.: Amazons do not *look* like men, they merely *act* like men. They're quite distinguishable; that's kind of the point.

Comment: @DVK: how is this asking for a list? It's asking for an *example*. If you're gonna consider everything with an example a "list", you might as well close the entire site.

Comment: @Martha - don't have to convince me. I'm all for yes/no questions and examples. But mine routinely get closed/DVed "because it's a list"

Comment: Well C.S. Lewis's Narnia had basically the same thing, but Lewis had heard much of Tolkien's work long before publication so this may not count.

Comment: Does Tolkien even write about female dwarf appearance anywhere, or is the "dwarf women have beards" thing from later than that?

Comment: Yes, is this actually even from Tolkien? Did it really appear in the books or is it just based on the dialogue from the movie mentioned in the linked question?

Answer (score 5):

I've never come across a mention of female dwarves looking like male dwarves outside Tolkien, but then I think you're overplaying its significance in Tolkien's work. As far as I know only one female dwarf is mentioned in any of the books I've read, [Dís](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/D%C3%ADs), and Aragorn's remark seems more of a throwaway line than anything significant. I wonder if Tolkien was just having a bit of fun.

Comment: You should read some of the Discworld books.

Comment: Oops yes, I meant independent of Tolkien. I'm not sure Pratchett counts as independent of Tolkien.

Comment: Is this even mentioned in the books? That male and female dwarves are hard to tell apart? Or is it just something from the movies? Wasn't it maybe Peter Jackson having the fun and not Tolkien?

Answer (score 0):

In Middle-earth Gimli says “some people say there are no dwarf women” so probably dwarf women look like dwarf men.

Comment: Or they mostly stay in their mines.

Comment: @Valorum: Or Tolkien was [lampshading](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LampshadeHanging) the lack of dwarf women.

Comment: This question is asking about works other than Tolkien.